# Iterate through ItemsControl's itemssource after it's been bound

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

Given the feedback of my last question, I have decided to delete it and ask again with a more detailed description of what I'm trying to accomplish:

Old Question:

> I've tried a lot of the event handlers for ItemControl only to find that everytime I tried to iterate the itemControl in it's event, it had not yet been bound by it's itemssource.
>
> Is there a way to fire an event after the ItemControl's ItemsSource has been bound?
>
> It has to be specific for ItemsControl not e.g. ListView.

What I wish to do, is iterate through an ItemsControl's items, that have been bound through itemssource. I wish to do this once and that has to be at some point after it's ItemsSource property has been bound through the ViewModel.

This could easily be done by using a ListView instead and using it's SelectionChanged event, but I wish to use an ItemsControl, as I am having problems using the VisualTreeHelper on a ListView.

A quick example of my code:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="BoundToObservableCollection" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=CalendarDateItemName, Path=CalendarItemsShow}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel x:Name="CatchThisControl"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

C#:

```
// I wish to execute this after the ItemsSoucr of my ItemsControl has been bound.
ItemsControl list = BoundToObservableCollection;
foreach (var item in list.Items)
{
    var _Container = list.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
    var _Children = AllChildren(_Container);
}

public List<UIElement> AllChildren(DependencyObject parent)
{
    var _List = new List<UIElement> { };
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); i++)
    {
        var _Child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        if (_Child is UIElement)
            _List.Add(_Child as UIElement); 
        _List.AddRange(AllChildren(_Child));
    }
    return _List;
}
```

In all of the events of ItemsControl, the itemssource is yet to be bound. How can I fire the AllChildren, after it's been bound?

Comment: One reason you'll find this isn't well supported is because it's very View-heavy and contrary to Data Binding  MVVM. Are you sure you really need a list of Controls?  Whatever you need should be possible by binding to a few item properties.

Comment: Basicly my ObservableCollection consists of Interface items, and I wish to display different controls in the ItemsControl based on the content of these interface items. Is there a better way to do this in xaml?

Comment: Yes. You can (should) use a [TemplateSelector](http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector). Or when the items are big enough to have their own View+ViewModel, use a framework like Caliburn to handle this almost invisibly.

Comment: See the below link to understand template selector implementation .    http://windowsapptutorials.com/windows-phone/listbox-windows-phone/implementing-a-custom-data-template-selector-in-windows-phone-8s-listbox-control/